# How to highlight cell if it's value is a multiple of a given number

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to apply conditional formatting to any cell within a range containing a value that is a multiple of itself.

***IE:*** Apply **bold** font to any cell of column `A` that is a multiple of 4 (4,8,12,16,20,24, ...).

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

After continuing to play around with functions, I was able to find a solution! Here is the solution for those trying to attempt something similar:

`=IF((AND((MOD(A:A,4) = 0),(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))))), true, false)`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @marikamitsos

Comment: Welcome to Webapps. I deleted your Data Validation mention and tag because the way you state your question does not support their presence. (_No need -as per site rules- to thank on the question. A polite and gentle behavior would suffice. You can always -as you did- use the comments area_) Please read [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking).